A strange behavior when checking `extends ReadonlyArray<any>`
See code:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UBKECGATA9gOwDYhgCdDUQAeAchgoD4AoUSKAIQWTSzwONMudobhoMAMYiIYYDDIAVKBAAewCNnQBnWDTYzBTGRDXAAjG1HjJ0mFoD011GInL0u6PsMAmUw4tlmN6xDEmIQuUG7AAMxe5lK+8koq6uwYOPhEJOSo2CBaAPwsUABcLP5Q9jEQ6EA
type A = ReadonlyArray<'A'>
type B = ReadonlyArray<'B'>
type AcceptA<T extends A> = T
type Test1 = AcceptA<A> //accepted
type Test2 = AcceptA<B> //error
type Test3 = AcceptA<B extends ReadonlyArray<any> ? B : B> // accepted

It could be accepted in Test3 but it's still the same B in Test2 which has an error.
Is there should be an error in Test3? Why not?

This has little to do with ReadonlyArray<T>. You can demo the same thing with just about any type function that depends on T, as shown in this playground link. And the behavior seems to be that once you use the unsafe any type in the conditional, the "true" case is now acceptable because any is considered assignable both to and from everything, whereas the "false" case is essentially narrowed to never, but it seems like a TS bug or limitation. I'm trying to narrow it down (changed between TS3.8 and TS3.9)

@jcalz Anyway it shouldn't be accepted in Test3.

Okay I've narrowed down what's happening, and this is working as intended. When you have a conditional type of the form T extends U ? V : W, the true case is given a substitution type which is similar to the intersection U & V.  So B extends F<any> ? B : B ends up becoming a substitution type like F<any> & B.  So AcceptA<F<any> & B> works because F<any> is assignable to F<A>. The any is unsound. If you want "correct" behavior you should use readonly unknown[] and not readonly any[]. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

Why it's U & V, does them have relations? Aren't they totally different types?

@jcalz And there is another question great man! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78800128/distributive-on-generic-types

Sorry, I misspoke... it's T extends U ? T : W should give you T & U... meaning that T has to be assignable to U because T extends U, so T is treated like T & U in what follows.  Does that make sense now? Should I write up an answer?

It makes sense. Thank you.@jcalz

Note that this is not specific to ReadonlyArray, but can be seen for almost any type function F<T> that depends on T:
type F<T> = ReadonlyArray<T>;
// or type F<T> = {x: T}
// or type F<T> = () => T
// or type F<T> = (x: T) => void

type A = F<'A'>
type B = F<'B'>
type AcceptA<T extends A> = T
type Test1 = AcceptA<A> // okay
type Test2 = AcceptA<B> // error
type Test3 = AcceptA<B extends F<any> ? B : B> // okay


This behavior is by design, as per microsoft/TypeScript#59430.
Conditional types produce what's called a "substitution type" in the true branch: see microsoft/TypeScript#43582:

We create "substitution types" in conditional types - when writing T extends U ? TrueBranch : FalseBranch, we substitute T with something that's sort of equivalent to T & U in the TrueBranch.

And the any type is intentionally unsafe, and is considered to be assignable both to and from just about evey other type. So even though F<'A'> and F<'B'> are not mutually assignable directly, both F<'A'> and F<'B'> are assignable to and from F<any>. That means you can put F<any> between F<'B'> and F<'A'> to get a chain of types that are assignable.
So B extends F<any> ? B : B is evaluated like B extends F<any> ? (B & F<any>) : B.  (Note that before TypeScript 3.9, there would not have been a substitution type there, because B isn't generic. But microsoft/TypeScript#37348 changed it so that you get substitution types even for specific types like B).

And now you can see what goes wrong.  B extends F<any> is the same as checking F<'B'> extends F<any>, and that's true.  So we get the true branch, which is equivalent to B & F<any>.  And that is acceptable for AcceptA:
type Test4 = AcceptA<B & F<any>> // okay

because intersections are assignable to both members of the intersection, meaning that B & F<any> is assignable to F<any> which is assignable to F<A>.
This is all working as intended. It's definitely strange, though.
Playground link to code

Although you explained why it happened. But why isn't it a bug? It shouldn't be accepted in Test3 in result.
