Distributive on generic types
How does TS perform Omit on generic types?
type DistributiveOmit<T, K extends keyof any> = T extends any ? Omit<T, K> : never;
type Data = { v: { k: 1 } }

function P<T extends Data>() {
    type T1 = Omit<T['v'], ''>['k']
    type T2 = DistributiveOmit<T['v'], ''>['k']
}

type T3 = Omit<Data['v'], ''>['k']
type T4 = DistributiveOmit<Data['v'], ''>['k']



Playground Link
In the code, I try to perform Omit and DistributiveOmit on generic type and normal type. They have different behaviors.
For normal types(out of the function,t3 and t4), they works fine. But t1 and t2 are different. How to explain this?

This doesn't seem to be a minimal example. Could you reduce it to this version? At some point the answer to questions like this is going to look like "TypeScript makes simplifying assumptions when dealing with generic conditional types because it cannot analyze them fully; these assumptions are often incorrect, and can yield different behavior compared to specific types". The exact nature of that would involve stepping through compiler code, and I'm not really prepared to do that.

@jcalz I updated my code and thank for your answer.
